# Postman environment variable returning null

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, postman, web-api-testing

I want to add a payload schema to an environment variable so that I can validate the response payload against the schema.

I have my environment variable defined as follows:

```
responseSchema: 
{ "properties":
      "firstname":
         {"type":"string" },
       "lastname": 
          {"type":"string"},
       "phonenumber": 
          {"type":"integer","format":"int64"}
       },
   "required":["firstname", "lastname", "phonenumber"]}
```

However, I can not access this environment variable within my Postman Test code.  I've tried accessing it by:

```
environment.responseSchema
```

However, this returns null.  How can I access the environment variable that I've created using postman.  The way I have implemented this is consistent with http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/07/28/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/ TIP #4: JSON Schema validation

Comment: how did you set the environment variable?

Comment: Great question @AndrewLohr - I used the 'EDIT COLLECTION' option and added the variable by its key and value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to be clear you are adding a collection variable, not an environment variable. [More on Postman variables](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables)

To access your collection variable you can do `pm.variables.get("responseSchema")` in the Tests script tab.

To be a bit more complete you should parse it as well.

```
var mySchema = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get("responseSchema"));
console.log(mySchema.properties.firstname.type);
```

Also I believe your object is invalid you probably meant to do

```
{
    "properties": {
        "firstname": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastname": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "phonenumber": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
        }
    },
    "required": ["firstname", "lastname", "phonenumber"]
}
```